# Regex to capture first match of everything between two colons

Tags: regex

Given this string:

`Equinox: *spamReceiveTask: Mar 17 12:34:39.264: #CAPWAP-3-DTLS_CONN_ERR: capwap_ac.c:934 00:3a:9a:30:f5:90:  DTLS connection not found forAP  192.168.99.74 (43456), Controller: 192.168.99.2 (5246) send packet`

I want to match everything between Equinox: and the next colon.  So my match should be *spamReceiveTask

I tried this: 
`^.*\bEquinox:([^:]+):`

but it matches as `Equinox: *spamReceiveTask:`

I also tried the look ahead and behind option, but it matched all the things between all the semicolons in the string.  I only want to match all the characters between the first two colons with the colons excluded.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the lookbehind and lookahead assertion, would you please try:

```
(?<=Equinox:)[^:]+(?=:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is perfectly fine, and it is working. I guess the problem is in language specific regex utilities and probably you are using them wrong way; your desired output is in capturing group 1;

check the snippet below written in javascript, and uses [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with your pattern;

```js
let sample = `Equinox: *spamReceiveTask: Mar 17 12:34:39.264: #CAPWAP-3-DTLS_CONN_ERR: capwap_ac.c:934 00:3a:9a:30:f5:90: DTLS connection not found forAP 192.168.99.74 (43456), Controller: 192.168.99.2 (5246) send packet`;

//only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned as an array
let pattern = /^.*\bEquinox:([^:]+):/
let matchAndCaptureGroup = sample.match(pattern);
let captureGroup = matchAndCaptureGroup[1];
console.log("without global flag: ", captureGroup);

//------------------------------------------
//with global flag, capturing group is not return
//only the matched strings will return
pattern = /^.*\bEquinox:([^:]+):/g
let matchOnly = sample.match(pattern)[0];
console.log("with global flag: ", matchOnly);
```

Comment: I am using the regex in Graylog as part of a regex Extractor.  As I understand it Graylog regex uses Java Pattern.  It seems like standard regex works if I put it in a grok pattern, however if I try and create a regex extractor, it wants the Java pattern version.  I tried your pattern of /^.*\bEquinox:([^:]+):/g , but it comes back with no match.

Comment: @WilliamK  that is not "my" dude, If you look closely, I'd copy pasted the pattern you provided in your question, no change. those `/ /` are javascript way of defining a regex pattern. and with if its Java then the only thing you need to do to find how to get capturing groups with graylog

Comment: My bad.  Its all greek to me.  I am not a programmer, just trying to get a task done.  I appreciate your help.  I was able to get this to work as a different type of extractor.  Not sure how Graylog parses things in the background.  I was able to get tshiono's answer to work in the extractor type I was creating.